# Hyperlink and Highlight

Tags: vba, hyperlink, range, formula, highlight

What code/formula should I use to hyperlink from one sheet to a data range in another sheet? I do not want to define a particular cell as this data keeps changing. I am making a inventory diagram on one sheet and have the inventory listed on another. I want to be able to click on inventory slot B3 and have it hyperlink and highlight all the items that are listed under B-3. Would this be done using a VBA code or a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

We can do this without either formula or code.

Say we have a data area on Sheet2 that may move with the insertion or deletion of rows/columns.

Hi-light the area and assign a Name to it using the Name Box (to the left of the Formula Bar).

Then go to Sheet1; click on some cell and **Insert** > **Hyperlink**
Pick **To a place in this document** and then pick the Name assigned on Sheet2

Comment: Sure....try it out...it will grow.  If you select the block of cells, hi-light the block by using Format > Cells...

Comment: I think you are missing what I mean by highlight, I would like the cells that are related to B-3 to be highlighted out oa an inventory list

Comment: Now I am sure I don't know what you mean!

Comment: So in my inventory diagram I have a slot that shows B-3, on a separate sheet I have my inventory list, what I am looking to do is when you click B-3 on the diagram it jumps to all Items that are associated with B-3 and highlight them in yellow